# Can a VB.NET application be used in iOS?

Tags: ios, vb.net

I built a vb.net application about 6-7 years ago for somebody and today they asked me if I could move it to their iPad. After doing some quick google searches I'm pretty convinced its not possible, but wanted to ask here just in case.

A little bit about my application:
Uses a MS Access database,
Connects to 3 other computers via a shared network (Windows),
Prints to an epson receipt printer.

Is there anyway to salvage this or am I better off building it in another language like Java/Python?

Comment: So, very opinion based here.  Wouldn't be surprised if question gets closed pretty quick.  Being someone in pretty much the same situation a couple years back have a little experience.    Options are 1) RDP from iPad to windows machine running app.  Xamarin forms (Will require some level C# but that's not too much of a transition from VB.net) or Web application.  All have pros and cons.

Comment: Option 1 will be by far the simplest, but might not be the best user experience. Option 2 & 3 means a complete rewrite of UI, assuming separation of UI and Logic in current app, logic might be fine as is.  Will likely also require connector service like a web api for Data Access.

Comment: There is a free plugin for Visual Studio that will convert VB.NET code to C#. It works pretty well. If your app has a GUI, you might be able to use C# and Xamarin to migrate it to iOS.